# create utils.py in AWS lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I had a `def hello()` function in my `home/file.py` file. I created a `home/common/utils.py`file and moved the function there.
Now, I want to import it in my file `file.py`.

I imported it like this: `from utils import hello` and `from common.utils import hello` and the import in my file doesn't throw an error. However, when I run it on AWS Lambda, I get an error that:

`Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'file': No module named 'utils'`

How can I fix this? without having to use Ec2 or something...

```
data "archive_file" "file_zip" {
  type             = "zip"
  source_file      = "${path.module}/src/file.py"
  output_file_mode = "0666"
  output_path      = "${path.module}/bin/file.zip"
}
```

Comment: What is the hierarchy of files in the packaged ZIP file that you uploaded to Lambda?

Comment: Not sure what you mean..I just run terraform init, apply and it happens automatically. How can I check the structure @jarmod

Comment: When you deploy a Lambda function, regardless of which IaC tool you use, you provide a packaged deployment artifact (a ZIP file of your code and dependencies). You typically do that by zipping your code and dependencies into lambda.zip, for example, then indicating that file in the `aws_lambda_function` resource in your Terraform template, then Terraform takes it and deploys it.

Comment: I updated the qs with how I zip the file content. not sure if this is what u meant by the hierarchy @jarmod

Answer (score 2):

The deployment package that you're uploading only contains your main Python script (file.py). Specifically, it does not include any dependencies such as common/utils.py. That's why the import fails when the code runs in Lambda.

Modify the [creation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file) of your deployment package (file.zip) so that it includes all needed dependencies.

For example:

```
data "archive_file" "file_zip" {
  type             = "zip"
  output_file_mode = "0666"
  output_path      = "${path.module}/bin/file.zip"

  source {
    content  = file("${path.module}/src/file.py")
    filename = "file.py"
  }

  source {
    content  = file("${path.module}/src/common/utils.py")
    filename = "common/utils.py"
  }
}
```

If all of your files happen to be in a single folder then you can use `source_dir` instead of indicating the individual files.

Note: I don't use Terraform so the `file(...)` with embedded interpolation may not be 100% correct, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, properly follow this standard URL:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html (refer section with title:- Deployment package with dependencies)

Now, if you notice, in the end of section,

```
zip -g my-deployment-package.zip lambda_function.py
```

Follow the same command for your utils file:-

```
zip -g my-deployment-package.zip common/    
zip -g my-deployment-package.zip common/utils.py
```

Ensure that, in `lambda_function`, you are using proper import statement like:-

```
from common.utils import util_function_name
```

Now, you can upload this zip and test for yourself. It should run.

Hope this helps.